# Tower on a slope problem

Tags: trigonometry

I have the following setup:

[image]

Nothing else is known apart from the 2 distances and the 2 angles and I need to calculate h. How can I do this?

Comment: Technically, you have been given _three_ angles. Or are you just assuming that the right angle is right because it _looks_ right?

Comment: @Arthur Right, forgot about that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the triangle with side lengths: $h$ and $30$, you can find the length of the other side. Call this length, $x$. Then by the Sine Rule,

$$\frac{x}{\sin 22.92}=\frac{50}{\sin (180-22.92-(180-44.47))}$$

Then use the Law of Cosines to find $h$:

$$h^2=x^2+30^2-60x\cos 44.47$$

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Use the [law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) for triangles $$\frac{\sin \alpha}{a}=\frac{\sin \beta}{b}=\frac{\sin \gamma}{c}$$